# Getting Topo to Raster Crash using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, anudem

I want to create a Raster file by Topo to Raster with known points and their values.
Input is a point shapefile with elevation (PointElevation).
Output Cell Size should be 50m within an Area 100*100 km².

Is the computing capacity a problem?

The problem is, that the tool crashes all the time without any notice. No Crash information by ArcMap and of course no error message.

I tried it by exporting the result as a TIFF to a standard folder and to a geodatabase.

Does anyone know, why the tool is crashing all the time?

Comment: Tool crashes are an issue for Tech Support. They tend to be data-specific and are usually related to corrupt data or a corrupted application (disk failure). There isn't any way we can help you beyond telling you to reinstall and validate your dataset(s).

Comment: Consider if you're running out of memory part way through the processing. 100km * 100km at 50m resolution is an output file with 4 million pixels.

Comment: Your raster isn't too big, just try to set environment extent and re-run. Perhaps consider to use other interpolation method because topo2raster does great with contours and b) very slow

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will definitely run it again by using a specified extent and to load the points from a gdb.
Hopefully this helps. We will see.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to try:

- Ensure there are no spaces or special characters in your file
  paths. That includes all inputs and outputs.
- Make your study area smaller, you may need more resources on
  the machine to process an area that large.
- Load your shapefile into a File Geodatabase and use the feature class as your input instead of the shapefile
- Write the output raster to a new/empty file geodatabase. I tend to have better luck processing rasters into a FGDB first, then exporting to TIFF or whatever else.